# Save and Execute returns previous row and current row in cassandra

Tags: java, cassandra, datastax

I'm on **cassandra 2.1** and have what is probably a newbie question here.

I overwrite an existing row with a newer timestamp (Date column).

```
QueryBuilder.insertInto(...)
session.execute(statement);
then do 

String sql = "SELECT * FROM "+keyspace+"."+tablename;
ResultSet resultSet = session.execute(sql);
```

I get two rows returned. One is the statement previous to the insertInto statment and the other is the new value updated by the insertInto statment.

How do I get only one row? `cqlsh` shows only one row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have probably defined your table to use your Date column as a clustering column.  This is used for collecting time series data, so inserting a row with a different timestamp creates a new row rather than updating an existing row.

If you want to update (overwrite) an existing row, all the fields you have listed for the PRIMARY KEY must have identical values.

Also if you are using the UPDATE statement, be aware that UPDATE and INSERT do the same thing in Cassandra, so using UPDATE is just like an INSERT if the key values don't exactly match an existing row.

Comment: No date is not a clustering column. Problem happens only if save and get are in the same thread. The get gets previous run's save and this runs save.
eg. prev db had row1.
This run I did save row1 again and then get ."I get two rows everything is same except for the date which is not a clustering column. Again cqlsh returns one row, and my next run with only get returns one row.

Comment: It shouldn't matter if the save and get are in the same thread.  Could you show your table schema and what values you are inserting?

Comment: schema is key1 blob, key2 blob, key3 blob, key 4 blob, vals blob, ts date
primary key is ((key1,key2),key3, key4)

Values are U1, X, Y, Z, hello, new Date
The new Date is what keeps changing every insert.
again cql is fine. The QueryBuilder.selection.all and iteration gives two rows, only if preceded by a save

Comment: I accepted your answer as it was my fault with the inserts. Your answer helped me in the right direction.